# How to unit tests an AWS Lambda handler with Dagger2 and Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, aws-lambda, mockito, dagger-2

I have some trouble trying to figure out how to write unit tests for an AWS Lambda handler. Here is an example:

**App.kt** is the AWS lambda handler class.

```
class App : RequestHandler<Any, Any> {
    private val component: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.create()
    }
    override fun handleRequest(input: Any, context: Context): Any {
        component.getBusinessLogic().doSomething()
        // code
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.kt** is the Dagger2 component to get the business logic.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun getBusinessLogic(): BusinessLogic
}
```

**AppModule.kt** is the Dagger2 module.

```
@Module
abstract class AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAmazonECS(): AmazonECS = AmazonECSClient.builder().build()
}
```

**BusinessLogic.kt** is the business logic for the AWS lambda function

```
class BusinessLogic @Inject constructor(...) {
    fun doSomething(): Any{
        // code to use AmazonECS
    }
}
```

Now, here is how I would like to test **`App.kt`** by mocking the BusinessLogic class.

**AppTest.kt**

```
class AppTest {
    @Test
    fun `test something`() {
        val mockLogic = mock(BusinessLogic::class.java)
        val app = App()
        `when`(mockLogic.doSomething()).thenReturn(...)

        app.handleRequest(...)
    }
    @Test
    fun `test exception`() {
        val mockLogic = mock(BusinessLogic::class.java)
        val app = App()
        `when`(mockLogic.doSomething()).thenThrow(...)

        assertThrows<...> { app.handleRequest(...) }
    }
}
```

So, my trouble is that I'm not sure how to use a mocked `BusinessLogic` instance. The **`App`** class must have an empty constructor for AWS lambda to instantiate. Modifying the code such as creating a secondary constructor just for unit testing does not feel right.

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: My suggestion would be to move the logic you want to test into a component separate from the App class. Then you can unit test it and inject it into your App class and use it from there.

Comment: @DominikG. I already have. They are in the `BusinessLogic` class. The code in the `App` class is specific to AWS lambda such as ensuring the correct Request/Response. Or are you also saying that I should also create another abstraction layer specifically for the AWS lambda-specific code?

Comment: I think it could be a good option. Then you have a one-liner in your App class that simply delegates to this new component. Your App class wouldn't really need unit testing then. Otherwise, I think you'd have to change your production code in order to make it unit testable, as you've already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Dominik G. for the comments and here is a solution based on the conversation.

**App.kt** is modified so that there is only one line and as such do not need to be unit tested.

```
class App : RequestHandler<Any, Any> {
    private val component: AppComponent by lazy {
        DaggerAppComponent.create()
    }
    override fun handleRequest(input: Any, context: Context): Any {
        return component.getLambdaLogic().handleRequest(input, context)
    }
}
```

**LambdaLogic.kt** now holds the logic to specifically for AWS lambda.

```
class LambdaLogic @Inject constructor(businessLogic: BusinessLogic) {
    fun handleRequest(input: Any, context: Context): Any {
        businessLogic.doSomething()
        // code
    }
}
```

**AppComponent.kt** is modified to return the `LambdaLogic` instead of the `BusinessLogic`.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {
    fun getLambdaLogic(): LambdaLogic
}
```

**LambdaLogicTest.kt** tests the AWS lambda logic.

```
class LambdaLogicTest{
    @Test
    fun `test something`() {
        val mockBusinessLogic = mock(BusinessLogic::class.java)
        val lambdaLogic = LambdaLogicTest(mockBusinessLogic)
        `when`(mockBusinessLogic.doSomething()).thenReturn(...)

        lambdaLogic.handleRequest(...)
    }
    @Test
    fun `test exception`() {
        val mockBusinessLogic = mock(BusinessLogic::class.java)
        val lambdaLogic = LambdaLogicTest(mockBusinessLogic)
        `when`(mockBusinessLogic .doSomething()).thenThrow(...)

        assertThrows<...> { lambdaLogic.handleRequest(...) }
    }
}
```

Using this approach, there is no longer a real need to unit test `App.kt` and we can also unit tests the AWS lambda logic.